# Can we always predict the ground state's phase of an unfrustrated quantum model with it's classical approximation?

Tags: condensed-matter, approximations, phase-diagram

Let's say, that we want to make a phase diagram of the Heisenberg XXZ model

$$ H = - \left (  J \sum_{\left<i,i'\right>, i < i'} \bar{S}_i \cdot \bar{S}_{i'} + \lambda \sum_{\left<i,i'\right>, i < i'} S_i^z S_{i'}^z + \sum_i D(S_i^z )^2 \right), $$

on a lattice without frustrations (e.g. a honeycomb one), where the $Z$ axis is chosen as the out of plane one. State of such a system can be approximated with a classical model, where we restrict the possible directions of spins' alignment to only four directions. We can predict the energy and corresponding phase of the groundstate by getting the minimum energy among the four possible ones:

$$ E_{FM,Z} = -2S^2 D - 3S^2 (J + \lambda ),$$
$$ E_{AF,Z} = -2S^2 D + 3S^2 (J + \lambda ),$$
$$ E_{FM,XY} = -3S^2J,$$
$$ E_{AF,XY} = +3S^2J,$$

where $FM$ and $AF$ indices correspond to ferromagnetic and antiferromagnetic phases, and $Z$ and $XY$ indices tell the direction, in which the spins are aligned (out of plane or in plane, respectively).

My question is, **can we always predict the phase of an unfrustrated quantum model with its classical approximation**? What information cannot be retrieved from such simplified model?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean by restricting the model to only four possible spin directions? Don't think I've heard of that as a quantum-classical mapping before.

Comment: @Anyon I edited my question to give more information. Sorry for the delay.